# Can we make path dynamic in angular? If not what should be the approach?

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angular8

I want to retrieve data from firebase realtime database by clicking the button as View lots. I have given the path as `/plats/bigfork/lots`. So it's just retrieving the data of bigfork. But as we can see, it's static. So how can I make the dynamic I'd in place of bigfork, so I can retrieve data with respect of the I'd which I have clicked.

Editlots is the html page in which I want to display the data.

**Component.ts**

```
 this.itemRef = db.list('/plats/bigfork/lots');
 this.lot$ = this.itemRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions
       .map(action => ({ 
                key: action.payload.key, 
                ...action.payload.val() 
        }));  
 });
```

**Component.html**

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <button type="button" 
          routerLink="editlots" 
          class="btn btn-info" 
          style="font-size: 15px; text-align: center; margin:0 auto; display: block;">
      View Lots
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @georgeawg could you help me out ?

Comment: Make **environments variable**  file. In this file, you can declare different routes based on conditions.

Or Another solution is to make a JSON in which you can store all the routes based on some condition. e.g
`{
  "cond1": "/plats/bigfork/lots",
  "cond2": "/plats/def/lots",
  "cond3": "/plats/abc/lots"
}`

Comment: i havn't get it

Answer (score 0):

**To achieve this we have three methods. They are explained one by one below.**

**First Method:** Make an environment variable file *env-var.service.ts* and declare your dynamic variable. Use this variable in your .ts file. You can change it when you need.

**env-var.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class EnvVarService {
  public route = 'bigfork';
  constructor() { }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EnvVarService } from './env-var.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  itemRef: any;

constructor (
  private _env_var: EnvVarService
) {

}
  myFunc() {
    this.itemRef = db.list(`/plats/` + this._env_var.route  + `/lots`);
    // ... Further code
  }
}
```

HTML will be same as you described.

**Second Method:** Make a JSON in which you can store all the routes based on some condition and then fetch the corrected route based on condition. You can also store this JSON outside this file.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EnvVarService } from './env-var.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  itemRef: any;

  json = { "cond1": "/plats/bigfork/lots", "cond2": "/plats/def/lots", "cond3": "/plats/abc/lots" }

constructor () {}

  myfunc(condition) {
    let route_value = '';
    for (let key in this.json) {
      if (key == condition) {
        route_value = this.json[key];
      }
    }
    this.itemRef = db.list(route_value);
  }
  // Rest code will be same
}
```

HTML will be same.

**Third Method: ** You can take it input from the user also. 
**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EnvVarService } from './env-var.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  itemRef: any;
  id: any;
constructor () {}
  myFunc() {
    this.itemRef = db.list(`/plats/` + this.value  + `/lots`);
  }
  // Rest code will be same
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input class="form form-control" style="display:inline" type="text" [(ngModel)]="id">
  <button type="button" 
          routerLink="editlots" 
          class="btn btn-info" 
          style="font-size: 15px; text-align: center; margin:0 auto; display: inline;">
      View Lots
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: In first method what is value? because i am getting error as Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EnvVarService'

Comment: Sorry, it's this._env_var.route

Comment: And in second method, how button click will get the id on which i am clicking without changing html?

Comment: Sir, i am getting the same results, by passing this._env_var.route as bigfork is ok, but if i pass route={{it.key}} then i am again getting the same error.

Comment: I dont want to retrieve data of bigfork only, i want to make it dynamic so that i can access data of dynamic id